# Rest the marker position + info window position

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having an issue with setting the position of the information window in Google Maps.

I know that its going to sound little worried but my desire is if the lat,lng are 0,0 I want to rest the marker to the center of the map in the US and rest the position of the information window to the same position.

Hope that someone can help me...

```
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"));

                //I'm getting from an object that I'm looping on it coordinates 0,0
                var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);


                // Create the marker on the map
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map
                });

                // Check if the LatLng are 0,0  - hide the marker redefine the position of the marker + map position.
                if (myLatLng == "0,0") {
                    var CenterLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.828127, -98.579404);
                    marker.setVisible(false);
                    marker.setPosition(CenterLatLng);
                    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(39.828127, -98.579404));
                }


                  var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                  '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                  '</div>'+
                  '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
                  '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                  '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
                  'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
                  'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
                  'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
                  '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
                  'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
                  'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
                  'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
                  'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
                  'Heritage Site.</p>'+
                  '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
                  'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
                  '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
                  '</div>'+
                  '</div>';

                  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                      content: contentString
                  });




                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker); // When The info window is open its grabbing the correct value that I defined in the above but it's opening it somewhere else on the map
                  });
```

Comment: What problem are you having with the code posted?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates that issue.

Comment: What is the problem with the code?

Comment: The infowindow when its opened its been open in the wrong location. Instead of opening the info window in this location: 39.828127, -98.579404

Answer (score 0):

To check for a google.maps.LatLng value use the [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) method .equals, not `(myLatLng == "0,0")`

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt56L10c/1/)

Comment: I tried that in my code but still the information window is been opened in other location instead of that location: 39.828127, -98.579404

Comment: That doesn't happen in my fiddle (no infowindow opens when the initial location is 0,0).  You are doing something else that you aren't telling us.  [Fiddle with the initial position _not_ at 0,0](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt56L10c/2/)

Comment: My plan is if the myLatLng are 0,0 I'm hiding the marker from the map and resetting the lat,lng to 39.828127, -98.579404. I have on the left hand side button that if I click on it's open the information window in the same location above but still I want to hide the marker. My issue is the info window been opened somewhere else on the map.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't do that.  It opens the infowindow on the _marker_, which you can't do if it isn't there.  **Second request** - Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates that issue.